# Angular 4 - Dynamically added meta tags not working

Tags: html, angular, meta-tags

I am using Meta service of Angular 4 -

```
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';

 constructor(private _router: Router,
    private _meta: Meta) {
 }

afterRequestSuccess(){
    this._meta.addTag({ property: 'og:description', content: "desc comes from api response" });
    this._meta.addTag({ property: 'og:image', content: "Image path comes from api resonse" });
}`
```

I can see on added tags in google chorme developer tool but I am trying on facebook Graph Object Debugger
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object that time is does not show in the debugger response list.

Can some one help ? thanks in advance.

Comment: For what URL? I doubt the debugger runs the JavaScript, I would you'd need server side rendering for this to work.

Comment: which URL you are asking about ? if I am adding hard-code meta tags it shows properly.

Comment: 1. The debugger needs a URL. How can we replicate the problem without that? 2. Sure, because then they're in the actual HTML, not generated by JS at runtime.

Comment: Are you sure that facebook is able to properly handle metatags in single page applications?

Answer (score 0):

Needs to be used - https://universal.angular.io/

If you want to convert existing app please follow the steps in given link -
https://codeburst.io/angular-server-side-rendering-using-angular-cli-bbde0c0eefe9